# Order of elements in free $\mathbb{Z}$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In Dummit and Foote, the authors state that "Free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules have no nonzero elements of finite order."

Why is this true? If $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then for any $x\in M$, there exists a subset $A\subseteq M$, unique nonzero elements $a_1,...,a_n\in A$ and unique $z_1,.,,,.z_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=z_1a_1+\cdots +z_na_n$. Why does this imply that $x$ has infinite order assuming $x$ is nonzero?

Comment: You should really spend some time looking for elements of finite order in, say, $\Bbb Z^2=\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the set $A$ you refer to is the basis of the module $M$. Since $x$ is nonzero, you may assume without loss of generality that $z_1\ne0$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$ satisfy $nx=0$, then
$$
0\cdot a_1 +\cdots + 0\cdot z_n = 0 = nx = nz_1\cdot a_1 +\cdots + nz_n\cdot a_n.
$$
This implies $nz_1=0$ because of the uniqueness of this expression and because $z_1\ne0$ we can conclude that $n=0$. Hence, there is no positive $n$ that annihilates $x$, which means that $x$ has infinite order.